# Есть ли способ использовать один конфиг для развертывания множества приложений?

Tags: развертывание, непрерывная-интеграция

У меня есть одно большое приложение, построенное по архитектуре SOA. Т.е. есть основной клиент и куча развернутых сервисов и служб. У всех них есть свои конфиги. Практически все они используют в своей работе одну и ту же базу данных. Соответственно у каждого в конфиге прописан ConnectionString к базе. Вот именно это и не нравится. Хочется только в одном файле указывать ConnectionString и все остальные конфиги подхватить должны, а не задавать одну и ту же строку подключения в десятках конфигов у всех сервисов. Существует ли какая-то возможность вынести этот ConnectionString в какой-то глобальный конфиг/файл/что-то еще? Machine.config использовать нельзя (точнее я крайне не хочу трогать такие системные конфиги). Есть какие-то решения у данной проблемы? Кто-то наверняка обладает знаниями в continuous delivery, подскажите.

Comment: Система управления конфигурациями, вроде Ansible?

Comment: Выделите микросервис, предоставляющий настройки соединения с базой.